# lesspipe.sh doesn't save tabstop setting

Tags: less

I like to use 4 spaces for tabstop, so my less settings is:

```
export LESS="-x4 -FRS"
export LESSOPEN='|lesspipe.sh %s'
```

But when I view source file with `less src.c` I see 8 spaces which is not what I want. When I view file without `lesspipe.sh` like this `cat src.c | less` or without highlighting `less src.c:` it looks just fine. How to overcome this behaviour?